# What is best practices to move the following code into a function?

Tags: functions, content

I have written this code block for my `page.php` file that determines if the content has a readmore tag, and then I break up the content using the `get_extended` function:

```
$content_arr = get_extended ( $post->post_content );

            if( strpos( get_the_content(), '<span id="more-' ) == true ) {
                echo wpautop($content_arr['main']);
                echo '<div class="morecontent">'. wpautop($content_arr['extended']).'</div>';
            }
            else {
                the_content();
            }
```

i think it would be more elegant to put this into a function using the `filter` command such as:

```
    function my_function_name($content) { 
            $content_arr = get_extended ( $content );

            if( strpos( $content, '<span id="more-' ) == true ) {
                echo wpautop($content_arr['main']);
                echo '<div class="morecontent">'. wpautop($content_arr['extended']).'</div>';

            //return $content
            }
            else {
                return $content;
            }
        }

    }

    add_filter('the_content', 'my_function_name', 1)
```

But I am a little lost on how to change this code to work with my function that passes in the `$content`, and since my original code is echoing the content, and in my function, I need to return content, I am getting lost. this is my first time building a function inside WP and I am looking for some help to maneuver content such as I am seeking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add numbers here to make this more clear. Even as I read it, knowing what each piece means, it can be semantically disorienting.

**Your original function** is calling (1)`$post->post_content` from the object and, depending on the conditional, echoing something or echoing what is returned in the function (2)`the_content()`, which is just (1)`$post->post_content` after it has run through (3)`get_the_content()` and (2)`the_content()`.

When you look [at the source of (3)`get_the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/) you can see what is happening to (1)`$post->post_content` before it gets to (2)`the_content()`

**Your second function** is receiving (1)`$post->post_content` ***after*** it has run through (3)`get_the_content()`, into (2)`the_content()` and then applying changes on it before it is echoed.

The (4)`apply_filters('the_content'...` you are hooking with your (5)`add_filter('the_content'...` is at [line 240 of *post-template.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L240) at the end of the function (2)`the_content()` that is calling the function (3)`get_the_content()` that is retrieving (1)`$post->post_content` from the current `$post` object.

(It's less *content, content, content* sounding when looking at each piece)

---

For your second function, you need to return (6)`$content` if you want there to be content for the function (2)`the_content()` to display. In your template you would just use (2)`the_content()`, as your conditional is being applied (by (4)`apply_filters('the_content'...` just before (2)`the_content()` returns.

I would add an `if ( [is_page()][3] && [is_main_query()][3] ) {}` wrapper inside your second function as well, so it isn't applied to non-page loops or sub-queries, as you need.

**BUT** the thing to check first, in my opinion, is to alter your original function so it uses (3)`get_the_content()` instead of (1)`$post->post_content` to be sure you can hook after that function has done its thing (which is what you are doing now) without losing your intended results.

Man I hope that's clear.

Look at the links to see the relation between each. It will really, really, help to understand each piece so you know where you are in the chain of events, and why you are hooking here or there etc.